# How can I pass multiple values from same column in a query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, ado.net

How can I pass multiple values from same column in a query? I am using vb.net and sql server database.

With my query an exception is generated saying that @booking_date has already been declared try a different variable....

My query is:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bookings where booking_date Between (@booking_date AND @booking_date) AND booking_time Between (@booking_time AND @bookinbg_time) AND game = " & x, con)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using BETWEEN instead of just `booking_date = @booking_date AND booking_time = @booking_time`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the parentheses around the variables?